# Error during select from a sub-query with jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jboss

I've tried to get result on this code:

```
List<SfsRepDemNote> lis = new ArrayList<SfsRepDemNote>();
            String sql = "select * from ( "
                    + "SELECT"
                    + "    core.SFS_REP_DEM_NOTES_ID,"
                    + "    Rank( ) Over( partition by core.hkid,core.scheme_code,core.demand_note_type Order by core.issue_date desc) rnk "
                    + "FROM"
                    + "    sfs_rep_dem_notes core"
                    + "    "
                    + "WHERE"
                    + "    core.void_ind = 'N'"
                    + "    AND   core.hold_ind = 'N'"
                    + "    AND   trunc(grace_due_date) <= TO_DATE( :dat ,'dd/mm/yyyy')"
                    + "    AND   hkid = :hkid "
                    + "    AND   exists ("
                    + "        SELECT"
                    + "            1"
                    + "        FROM"
                    + "            sfs_rep_dem_note_components com "
                    + "            JOIN sfs_loan_infos loinf ON com.sfs_loan_info_id = loinf.sfs_loan_info_id "
                    + "        WHERE"
                    + "            loinf.loan_ref_num in :ref  "
                    + "            and   core.sfs_rep_dem_notes_id = com.sfs_rep_dem_notes_id"
                    + "            AND   nvl(com.surcharge_unpaid,0) + nvl(com.instal_interest_unpaid,0) + nvl(com.instal_principal_unpaid,0) >= 1"
                    + "    )) where rnk = 1";
            Query query = super.getEntityManager().createQuery(sql);
            query.setParameter("dat", "01/02/2018");// letterDefaultDateFormat.format(defermentCase.getReceiveDate()));
            query.setParameter("hkid", "E80001");// defermentCase.getGaHkid());
            query.setParameter("ref", selectedValues);
            //logger.info(query.getParameterValue(3));

            List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
            logger.info("list =" + list.size());
            for (Object[] array : list) {
                //logger.info("id = " + array[0].toString());
                lis.add(findByPK(Long.parseLong(array[0].toString()),
                        SfsRepDemNote.class));
                // logger.info(tmpQuery.getResultList().size());
            }
            logger.info("end");
            return lis;
```

In some cases, I need to use "IN cause" on it. I've tried with `createSelectNativeQuery()` to get my result, but for the param :ref it can not be work on native Query, but in ejb ql I just got this error msg:

> Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select * from ( SELECT
>   core.SFS_REP_DEM_NOTES_ID,    Rank( ) Over( partition by
>   core.hkid,core.scheme_code,core.demand_note_type Order by
>   core.issue_date desc) rnk from    sfs_rep_dem_notes core     where 
>   2=2 and     core.void_ind = 'N'    AND   core.hold_ind = 'N'    AND
>   trunc(grace_due_date) <= TO_DATE( :dat ,'dd/mm/yyyy')    AND   hkid =
>   :hkid     AND   exists (        SELECT            1        from
>   sfs_rep_dem_note_components com             JOIN sfs_loan_infos loinf
>   ON com.sfs_loan_info_id = loinf.sfs_loan_info_id         WHERE
>   loinf.loan_ref_num in :ref              and
>   core.sfs_rep_dem_notes_id = com.sfs_rep_dem_notes_id            AND
>   nvl(com.surcharge_unpaid,0) + nvl(com.instal_interest_unpaid,0) +
>   nvl(com.instal_principal_unpaid,0) >= 1    ))  WHERE rnk = 1  ]. 
>   [125, 125] A select statement must have a FROM clause. [7, 7] The left
>   expression is missing from the arithmetic expression. [9, 125] The
>   right expression is not an arithmetic expression. [154, 799] The query
>   contains a malformed ending.  at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
>     at
>   hksarg.wfsfaa.isfast2.framework.jpa.WrappedEntityManager.createQuery(WrappedEntityManager.java:92)
>     at
>   hksarg.wfsfaa.isfast2.framework.jpa.SecuredEntityManager.getSecuredJpql(SecuredEntityManager.java:594)
>     at
>   hksarg.wfsfaa.isfast2.framework.jpa.SecuredEntityManager.createQuery(SecuredEntityManager.java:126)
>     at
>   hksarg.wfsfaa.isfast2.ejb.deferment.DefermentLetterUtilBean.getSFSOverdueDemandNote(DefermentLetterUtilBean.java:882)
>     at
>   hksarg.wfsfaa.isfast2.ejb.deferment.DefermentLetterUtilBean.getAdditionalInfoLetterContent(DefermentLetterUtilBean.java:419)
>     at
>   hksarg.wfsfaa.isfast2.ejb.deferment.DefermentLetterUtilBean.test(DefermentLetterUtilBean.java:116)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)
>     at
>   hksarg.wfsfaa.isfast2.framework.ejb.BaseBean.methodInterceptor(BaseBean.java:104)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringInterceptor.intercept(MonitoringInterceptor.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:272)
>     ... 136 more

I've tired on it, can everybody can give me some advice? thx for help

Comment: Try executing that sql query by removing parts of sql query one line or two at a time. By that you will find the error.

Comment: `createQuery` takes in JPQL. JPQL != SQL. Your query is SQL. You would find this simple fact in ANY JPA documentation. `createNativeQuery` takes in SQL. You'd find that in the same JPA documentation

Comment: What happened to your formatting skills?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `Query query = super.getEntityManager().createQuery(sql);`with `Query query = super.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);`assuming you are using a pure jpa implementation. Also edit your native query IN part from `loinf.loan_ref_num in :ref` to `loinf.loan_ref_num in (:ref)`.

Comment: I try it, but an other problem is I can't using list to put by result inside the in clause, do you have any advice on it?